# What do commentaries say about the different version of "Honor Thy Parents"?

Tags: kibbud-av-veim-honoring, parashas-yisro, aseres-hadibros, vaeschanan

Regarding the mitzva of **Honor Thy Father and Mother**, the reading of the Aseret Hadibrot in V'etchanan is slightly different than the previous reading in Yitro.

The words "*because God has commanded you*" and "*so it will be good for you*" have been added.

What do the commentaries say about this? Why were these words added? Was there a specific context in which is was important to say it differently this time?

Here is a side by side comparison, with Yisro on the left and V'etchanan on the right. ([taken from here](http://parsha.blogspot.ca/2011/01/ibn-ezra-on-aseres-hadibros-part-ii.html))

[image: Kabed es avicah differences]

Comment: Doesn't he explain that later on? http://parsha.blogspot.co.il/2011/01/ibn-ezra-on-aseres-hadibros-part-iv.html

Comment: The Midrash Tanatim states that the second tablents were (in one way) greater, since they; but not the first, state the associated blessing of goodness: 
: ולמען ייטב לך גדולים הן לוחות שניות יתר מן הראשונות שהשניות נאמר בהן טוב שנ' ולמען ייטב לך והראשונות לא נאמר בהן טוב If you are interested, I will post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding both phrases, R. Isaac Abravanel (Parashat Vaethanan ch. 5) writes:

> והנה אמר בדבור הזה כאשר צוך ה' אלהיך מה שלא אמר בשאר הדברות מפני שראה אדונינו משה להוסיף ולבאר בדבר הזה על מה שבא בדברות הראשונות. כי שם אמר בענין השבת /הכבוד/ למען יאריכון ימיך על האדמה אשר ה' אלהיך נותן לך. וכאן הוסיף ולמען ייטב לך. כאלו אמר כאן כבד את אביך ואת אמך כאשר צוך ה' ומאותו טעם אשר צוך ה' אלהיך בדברות הראשונות שהוא למען יאריכון ימיך ועוד לסבה שנית והוא למען ייטב לך.
>
> וענין השכר הזה הוא שבדברות הראשונות נתן השכר באריכות ימים כי בהיות האדם מכבד את אביו ואת אמו יאריך ימים ויהיו לו בנים ובני בנים ואמנם דור אביו יקלל ואת אמו לא יברך אין ספק שלא יראה זרעו ולא יאריך ימים כי יכרתו ימיו. וכמו שאמר (משלי י) ושנות רשעים תקצורנה. ואמר שהשכר ההוא מהארכת ימים יהיה על האדמה אשר ה' נותן להם בהיותם בגלות והוסיף עליו מרע"ה הנה ולמען ייטב לך. לומר שלא יחשב שהתועלת בכבוד האב והאם הוא בלבד אל האב המכובד והאם גם כן. כי גם כן ימשך התועלת ההוא אל הבן המכבדו כי בניו אחרי כן יכבדוהו גם כן כמו שהוא מכבד לאביו...וזהו אמרו ולמען ייטב לך. הנה התבאר הטעם למה אמר כאשר צוך ה' אלהיך בשני הדברות בלבד.

That is, the first statements said that one should honour one's parents to merit a long life. The latter set reference the reason given in the first set with the words כאשר צוך, and adds an additional reason: למען ייטב לך; that God will do good to us. To understand the additional good, one must first consider the implications of the first blessing. Although it promises a long life, this may be more of a blessing to one's parents than to one's self. Therefore, Moshe added the phrase ולמען ייטב לך to reassure them that the reward for honouring one's parents isnt merely a long life, it has a further benefit to the son; that his own children will honour him as well.

Regarding ולמען ייטב לך, the [Hizkuni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hezekiah_ben_Manoah) Deut. (5:16) states:

> ולמען ייטב לך יתור הוא על הראשונות כלומר אם תכבדם הקדוש ברוך הוא יתן לך עוד שכר טוב, ולפי שהראשונות חסרות אות טי"ת כתב ולמען כדי להשלים בהם כל אותיות אלפא ביתא פשוטות וכפולות.

That is, since the first statements lacked the letter ט, this line was inserted so that between them, all of the letters of the alphabet would be present.